# Saving data from custom forms in wordpress database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have created a PHP program that provides customised output based upon user input entered in HTML contact form.
The HTML form & PHP output is working fine.
However, when I am trying to save the data in WP database, I am not able to see any response.
I have not inserted any theme directory location in form action to enable the $region value to be processed in php form (if i am inserting a theme file, the program gets redirected to that URL on submission).
Please let me know how can I save the user input in a database.
Please find the code below:

```
<?php
    $region = $_POST['Region'];
    $Click_here_to_start_your_download = 'https://mydailysugar.info/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Blood-Glucose-Chart-A4-1.pdf';
    switch ($region) {
        case 'North':
            echo "<a href='$Click_here_to_start_your_download'>Click here to start your download</a>";
            die;
        case 'South':
            echo "<a href='$Click_here_to_start_your_download'>Click here to start your download</a>";
            die;
        case 'East':
            echo "<a href='$Click_here_to_start_your_download'>Click here to start your download</a>";
            die;
        case 'West':
            echo "<a href='$Click_here_to_start_your_download'>Click here to start your download</a>";
            die;
    }
    $name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $phone = $_POST['user_phone'];

    function insertuser($name, $email, $phone) {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mealplanner';
        $wpdb->insert($table_name, array
            ('user_name' => $name, 'user_email' => $email, 'user_phone' => $phone)
        );
    }

    insertuser($name, $email, $phone);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Meal Planner </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='POST'>
            <p>Name</p> <input type='text' name='user_name'>
            <p>Email</p> <input type='text' name='user_email'>
            <p>Phone</p> <input type='text' name='user_phone'>
            <p>Dropdown Box</p>
            <select name='Region' size='1'>
                <option value='North'>North
                <option value='South'>South
                <option value='East'>East
                <option value='West'>West
            </select>
            <br/>
            <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'><input type='reset' value='CLEAR'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a stand-alone script? If so, then `global $wpdb;` probably doesn’t exist to begin with. (Is this not getting you any errors? If not, then enable WB debug mode and proper PHP error reporting first of all!) If you want to use WP functionality in scripts outside of WP, then you need to embed the necessary WP core files first.

Comment: I am running this script on WP through an insert PHP plugin- it is not outside of WP. I am not getting any error. However, am not able to save the data in DB.

Comment: Well then do some proper debugging. Make debug outputs to check if those variables actually contain what you think they should, and check the return value of `$wpdb->insert`

Comment: Does the syntax look okay to you? I thought that since there is no custom theme URL, the data is not getting saved.